# How to align two Gtk3 Entry fields

Tags: python-3.x, alignment, gtk3

I've got a GUI that uses a GtkEntry widget to get some users input. Here's what it looks like:

[image]\

I've got it working like I want, other than the fact that the **To:** and **CC:** fields aren't aligned and that's *really* annoying.

Is there any way I can align them with each-other so they line up perfectly?

Comment: If you are using Glade, you should probably mention that. Also what container you are currently using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put them in a `Gtk.Grid` or use `Gtk.SizeGroup`.